# How to get newest recording in Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio-twiml

I'm making recordings in Twilio, using python. Just wondering how do I access the latest/newest recording that I've made? Cheers!

Making the recording:

```
resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
resp.say("Please record your message after the beep")
resp.record(maxLength="10", action="/handle-recording")
```

Sample code on accessing recordings, how would I code it for the latest? Thanks!

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "AC30bd8bdca7572344721eb96c15a5c0c7"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of recording objects with the properties described above
recordings = client.recordings.list()
```

Comment: And before somebody makes that comment, no that is not my API key.

Answer (score 1):

`recordings[-1]` should get you the last item in recordings, which should be the newest recording, as recordings are appended to the list. Make sure `recordings` is not empty otherwise you will get an `IndexError`.

Comment: How would I get the url of that file?

Comment: Recoding instance resources have URIs that you can access. See this documentation from Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance